# Why does implementation of abstract class not see overloaded pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

Given the following code example, why is the overloaded `AbstractBaseClass::DoAThing( const char* )` not visible as an inherited method in the `SomeEndClass` that implements the overloaded pure abstract `DoAThing( const char* const* )` method?

```
class AbstractBaseClass
{
    public:

        virtual void DoAThing( const char* withThis ) {}
        virtual void DoAThing( const char* const* withThat ) = 0;

        AbstractBaseClass() {}
        virtual ~AbstractBaseClass() {}
};

class SomeMiddlewareClass : public AbstractBaseClass
{
    public:

        void ThisIsCool() {}

        SomeMiddlewareClass() {}
        virtual ~SomeMiddlewareClass() {}
};

class SomeEndClass : public SomeMiddlewareClass
{
    public:

        void DoAThing( const char* const* withThat ) {}

        SomeEndClass() {}
        virtual ~SomeEndClass() {}
};

void SomeFunction()
{
    SomeEndClass* myClass = new SomeEndClass();

    myClass->DoAThing( "withThis" );
    ((SomeMiddlewareClass*)myClass)->DoAThing( "withThisToo" );

    delete myClass;
}
```

The compiler (and indexer) produce the following error on the `myClass->DoAThing( "withThis" );` line while the `((SomeMiddlewareClass*)myClass)->DoAThing( "withThisToo" );` line is accepted.

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void DoAThing(const char * const *)
>
> no matching function for call to ‘SomeEndClass::DoAThing(const char [9])’

Shouldn't the `SomeEndClass` inherit the `AbstractBaseClass::DoAThing( const char* )` implementation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: both virtual functions must be implemented. they are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `SomeEndClass::DoAThing()` function not only overrides the function inherited from the base class, but also *hides* the other overloads of that function in the base class.

You could add a `using` declaration to your `SomeEndClass` class:

```
using SomeMiddlewareClass::DoAThing;
```

Therefore:

```
class SomeEndClass : public SomeMiddlewareClass
{
    public:

        using SomeMiddlewareClass::DoAThing;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        void DoAThing( const char* const* withThat ) {}

        SomeEndClass() {}
        virtual ~SomeEndClass() {}
};
```

With this fix, you can see your program compiling in this [**live example**](http://ideone.com/ftSO7G).

Comment: Thank you. Choosing who to accept the answer from is something of a challenge... but since you were first across the enter key ~smile~ Thanks to @Jerry Coffin as well.

Comment: Interesting. For whatever reason my toolchain (Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27)) will not eat this unless I use `using AbstractBaseClass::DoAThing;`

Comment: @WhozCraig: Interesting. Does it complain on the `using` declaration? What is the error message?

Comment: It complains on the usage in `main()`, not the class decl. And I just figured out why. unlike the OP's code, I redeclared `void DoAThing( const char* const* withThat ) = 0;` in the middleware class (habit, I always either implement or redeclare as pure any inherited pure virtuals). Removing the re-decl allows your middleware using clause to work, otherwise it works with Jerry's base class using clause.

Answer (score 6):

In your base class `DoAThing` is not just virtual, but overloaded.

The function in the derived class overrides one of those overloads and *hides* the other.

You're then trying to call the other, which is hidden.

You can make the hidden function visible in the derived class with a `using` declaration:

```
using Base::DoAThing;
```

...but whether you should is a separate (more complex) question.